# How to retrieve data by comparing equality of the value of the sum of some rows with other row value from one table?

Tags: mysql, database, laravel

[image: I have a table that contain reports for transactions]

I would like to retrieve the records that are not equal in sum of two credit amount and debit amount those have same journal id.

Comment: what version of mysql are you using?   there are two completely different ways to do this, depending on version

Comment: 10.4.8-MariaDB version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use the SUM window function for this:

```
select id,journal_id,dr,cr,description,tran_type
from (
    select *,
        sum(dr) over (partition by journal_id) dr_total,
        sum(cr) over (partition by journal_id) cr_total
    from transactions
) transactions_with_totals
where dr_total <> cr_total;
```

For versions earlier than mysql 8 or mariadb 10.2, window functions are not available.  In that case, you would do:

```
select transactions.*
from transactions
join (
    select journal_id,
        sum(dr) dr_total,
        sum(cr) cr_total
    from transactions
    group by journal_id
) journal_id_totals using (journal_id)
where dr_total <> cr_total;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since there is a Laravel tag, I thought I would post a query builder version of the accepted answer by @ysth.

```
$transactionTotals = DB::table('transactions')
                   ->select('journal_id', 
                             DB::raw('SUM(dr) dr_total'), 
                             DB::raw('SUM(cr) cr_total'))
                   ->groupBy('journal_id');

$transactionsWithDifferentCreditAndDebit = DB::table('transactions')
            ->joinSub($transactionTotals, 'transaction_totals', function ($join) {
                $join->on('transactions.journal_id', '=', 'transaction_totals.journal_id');
            })
            ->whereColumn('dr_total', '<>', 'cr_total')
            ->get();
```